# Jquery xml file provides information details page pulls all info instead of selected

Tags: jquery, html, xml, dynamic

I am trying to build on some basic ideas. I have an xml file which I have no problems loading onto a list type menu . My xml file has about 300 records and each record contains approviamtely 45 fields. (LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, ADDRESS, etc).
I can get the list menu created but I cannot manage figure out how to load the details page for only the person picked from the menu list item.  I have googled and I am this is complete user error on my part.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<body> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "COMBINED.xml",
               dataType: "xml",
               success: function(xml) {
                   $(xml).find('COMBINED').each(function(){
                       var id = $(this).attr('ID')

                       var JPG = $(this).find('JPG', 'FIRSTNAME').text()

                       var FIRSTNAME = $(this).find('FIRSTNAME').text()
                       var LASTNAME = $(this).find('LASTNAME').text()
                       var SCHOOL = $(this).find('SCHOOL').text()
                       var DISABILITY = $(this).find('DISABILITY').text()
                       var TITLE = $(this).find('TITLE').text()





      $('<li></li>').html('<a href="#DETAILSPAGE"'+id+'">'+FIRSTNAME +' '+ LASTNAME + '<p>'+SCHOOL+ '</p></a>').appendTo('#LIST');
   var $divToAppend=  $('#DETAILS')
   var detailsitem=$('<div></div>').attr('id','#DETAILSPAGE').html("<h1></h1>");

  $('<li></li>').html(DISABILITY).appendTo('#DETAILS' )

  })
      ;}

      })
      </script>

  <div data-role="page" id="page" data-theme="b">
      <div data-role="header">
          <h1>Page One</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content"> 
          <ul data-role="listview">
              <li><a href="#LISTPAGE">Page Two</a></li>
              <li><a href="#page3">Page Three</a></li>
              <li><a href="#page4">Page Four</a></li>
          </ul>     
      </div>
      <div data-role="footer">
          <h4>Page Footer</h4>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div data-role="page" id="LISTPAGE">
      <div data-role="header">
          <h1>Page Two</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">
      <ul data-role="listview" id="LIST"></ul>
      </div>
      <div data-role="footer">
          <h4>Page Footer</h4>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div data-role="page" id="DETAILSPAGE">
      <div data-role="header">
          <h1>Page Three</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content" >    
<ul data-role="listview" id="DETAILS"></ul>

      </div>
      <div data-role="footer">
          <h4>Page Footer</h4>
      </div>
  </div>


  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: FYI: you really shouldn't nest <P> tags inside of <A HREF>.

Comment: The last few lines of your jQuery code don't really make any sense to me. #DETAILS is an unordered list, not a div; and you create `detailsitem`, but never do anything with it. What is your desired result?

Comment: changed the p tags. I am trying to chose the child's name from the listpage and grab all the xml data i have on the child and place it in a details page.

Comment: Place it how? Do you want to add it as list elements to #DETAILS ?

Comment: Yes. Currently it loads every childs district in the list I just want to add the childs district (and other information in the xml file) into the details

Comment: How is a single child being selected?

Comment: by choosing the li created in this: $('<li></li>').html('<a href="#DETAILSPAGE"'+id+'">'+FIRSTNAME +' '+ LASTNAME + '<br>'+SCHOOL+ '</a>').appendTo('#LIST');

Comment: I would be happy to just be able to click the child's name and then have a page that puts in just the childs district information

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked:
After setting up variables with the information.
Had some great help from a great book Jay Blanchard's Applied Jquery Book.

```
  $('<li class="memberInfo" name="'+thisID+'"></li>').html(THISMEMBERDETAIL).appendTo('#DETAILS');

     $('a').live('click', function(){
    /* get the name attribute of the link clicked */
    var thisMemberID = $(this).attr('name');
    /* if any previous member info was showing, hide it */
    $('.memberInfo').hide();
    /* show the current member info */
    $('li[name="'+thisMemberID+'"]').show();
       });
   });
```